# How to use eraser before and after scaling of a image in objective-c iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, erase

I am working on some image processing project where I need to implement eraser on a image. I have to also implement pinch effect to scale the image smaller or larger. Pinch is working nice. Eraser also works perfect If I dont scale the image by pinch. But when I use pinch and then use eraser. The image goes blur. I have implemented eraser on `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Below is the code for eraser.

```
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:tattooImage];
if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
     lastPoint = translatedPoint;
     //lastPoint.x += 60;
     //lastPoint.y += 60;
}
else
{
     CGPoint currentPoint = translatedPoint;
     //currentPoint.x += 60;    
     //currentPoint.y += 60;

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tattooImage.frame.size);
     [tattooImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,tattooImage.frame.size.width, tattooImage.frame.size.height)];
     CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext( ),kCGBlendModeClear);
     CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
     CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext( ), 25.0);

     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
     CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
     CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
     CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()) ;

     tattooImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     lastPoint = currentPoint;
}
```

Please provide any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. There is a small change which I did and I got the desired result. I changed `tattooImage.frame.size` with `tattooImage.bounds.size` everywhere in the code, and It worked perfectly. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389202/pete-c

Answer (score 4):

The way image manipulation programs work is not by working directly on what you see on the screen (except maybe MSPaint...), but instead by applying all work to a 1:1 scale copy, and showing you the zoomed in version of that.

What you need to do is keep a the image you are working on stored off screen. The image that is displayed on screen will need to be copied from this source.

You can then calculate where all the touch events happen in relation to the image relatively, and instead of applying your erase/draws directly to the image on screen, apply them to the un-zoomed image scaled appropriately.

Something along the lines of:

1. Store copy of image for working on.
2. Get location of touch.
3. Calculate relative position based on scale/location in view
4. Apply eraser touches to stored copy of image
5. Update on screen copy of the image at current zoom level/position.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. First of all you are using the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to move the object. You can simply us `UITouch` , in that the implementation would be easier. I have provided some code :-

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:imageView] anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawingView];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingView.frame.size);
    [drawingView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawingView.frame.size.width, drawingView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext( ), 5.0);
    if (eraserSelected)
    {
        CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext( ), 10.0);
    }
    [self changeBrushColor];
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() , lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()) ;
    drawingView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;  
    }
```

Now you can make your own `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` method.

Comment: The problem is not with the movement or with the eraser. The problem is using scaling and eraser simultaneously. Can you provide the solution regarding that?